# Set own Dialect in Hibernate Properties / Path

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written my own dialect for Hibernate. now i want to add it in my properties file. This is the default (which is working fine):

```
hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

but what path shall I use if I add my class?

```
hibernate.dialect= myApp.dialect.SubSQLServerDialect.java
```

this does not work. An absolute path from the root folder of my system doesn't work too. Structure is like:

```
Project/src/myApp/dialect/SubSQLServerDialect.java
Project/lib/hibernate3.jar/org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in [this](http://keyurj.blogspot.ru/2012/12/creating-custom-dialect-in-hibernate.html) tutorial you can use just `hibernate.dialect=myApp.dialect.SubSQLServerDialect`
Of course, your class should be on classpath.

Comment: Ha, it was just the .java that was too much. Thanks!!